# Prisma data exists or not

Tags: prisma

In prisma, I want to check if the data for specific user's exists, if so, pass, if data not exists, process and add the data. How can I do this?

```
    const users = await prisma.user.findUnique({
        where: {
            email: session.user.email
        },

        wallet: {
            contains: "0x",
            },
        })
        
            
    if(users !== 0){
        console.log("wallet already signup");
    }else{ ...
```

Answer (score 1):

`upsert` is what you want here. It'll create the record if it doesn't exist. Note hhow the update clause is empty.

```js
const upsertUser = await prisma.users.upsert({
  where: {  email: session.user.email },
  update: {},
  create: {
    name: 'Name',
  },
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```js
    const user = await prisma.users.findFirst({
      where: {
        email: session.user.email,
        wallet: {
          contains: '0x',
        },
      },
    });

    if (users !== 0) {
      console.log('wallet already signup');
    } else {
      // ...
    }
```